# phpstorm Using swig Template Engine?

Tags: node.js, express, phpstorm, swig, swig-template

how to install or configure SWIG Template Engine in JetBrains PhpStorm 8.0.2?

I have:

- "PhpStorm": 8.0.2
- "node.js" v0.10.36
- "express": 4.10.6
- "swig": 1.4.2

How do I make swig template settings for my PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help: I added in Settings -> File Types -> Twig: *.html - and now works with HTML files as Twig files (Twig and Swig are the same in this context)

Update:
configured my swig files with extension *.s.html as Twig files, now I use Swig and HTML files without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm has no proper support for Django-like templates ATM.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7814 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Comment: WebStorm no, JetBrains PhpStorm 8.0.2

Comment: @LuisPrieto Yeah, my mistake. In any case: it's the same thing in this particular regard: PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP (simply speaking). This ticket is filled under WebStorm as it's a node.js related thingy. **In any case:** PhpStorm supports twig templates which is Django alike as well. See if associating your swig templates with "Twig file" file type will be enough (I have no idea how different syntax they both may have).

Comment: sorry I did not get much of PhpStorm much less WebStorm, I have one week trying to configure it to start a project, I'm really new at this, my knowledge is of java and oracle, as you can imagine I have no idea what I'm doing. for more I read I can not find how to make settings that I require and English is not my native language, and everything I read tells me I can express use templates. how? i do not know. but if I succeed lay it over here. sorry for my bad English, I speak Spanish